# Laravel Collections: Finding the intersection

Tags: laravel, collections

Here is how I currently find the intersection of multiple Laravel collections:

```
$stuff = [
    collect(['a','b','c','d']),
    collect(['b','c','d','e']),
    collect(['c','d','e','f']),
];

$i = 0;
foreach ($stuff as $current) {

    $i++;

    if ($i === 1) {
        $common = $current;
    } else {
        $common = $common->intersect($current);
    }
}

dd($common);
```

Is there a more efficient method?  It seems a bit clumsy to have to treat the first collection differently (via the `if...else...`).

Laravel has so many good collection methods I suspect there is a more elegant approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-reduce) may be a option for this:

```
$intersection = collect([
    collect(['a','b','c','d']),
    collect(['b','c','d','e']),
    collect(['c','d','e','f']),
])->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    return $carry->empty() ? $item : $carry->intersect($item);
});
```